# find the trace and the determinant of an nxn diagonizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, diagonalization

can someone help me with the question? your help will be appreciated

Question: if A is a nxn diagonizable matrix, determine tr(A) and Det(A) as functions of eigenvalues of of the matrix?

Comment: This was asked 10 minutes ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037621/determining-mboxtra-and-deta-as-functions-of-the-eigenvalues-of-a-ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write the **Jordan Normal Form** for the matrix $A$ we get:

$$A=P^{-1}JP$$

and $J$ has all eigenvalues on the diagonal but $J$ not necessearily is a diagonal matrix.

So $\det(A)=\det(J)$ and $\det(J)$ is the product of the eigenvalues.

Now using the known relation $\mbox{tr} (AB)=\mbox{tr} (BA)$ we have:

$$\mbox{tr} (A)=\mbox{tr} (P^{-1}JP)=\mbox{tr} (JPP^{-1})=\mbox{tr} (J)$$

and $\mbox{tr} (J)$ is the sum of eigenvalues.